# How to properly add missing libraries and frameworks to existing Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, frameworks, libraries

in the past I have developed some simple iOS apps and today I saw that "phyphox", an app I would like to customize, is open source. So I downloaded the project, however it relies on some third-party libraries. [Picture of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qRQE.png). I tried to compile these libraries and added the .framework files to the framework folder of the Xcode project, but the error messages wouldn't go away. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey, just to be sure, you've already tried to add these files through a Podfile? In addition to downloading the project? If not, I can tell you how. I think this would fix your issue.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! Haven’t done that yet. The only thing I’ve tried so far was to add the .framework files and I also edited the "Build Phases" section. Guess that wasn’t enough?

Comment: Okay cool, I think I have your answer...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create a podfile to download everything properly. [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuMZZtQpB6Y) explains it really well! I've never done it the .framework way before, but I believe that podfiles will solve your problem because it's installed through your terminal and becomes a large piece of your project. I hope this helps! :)